# Insert javascript reservation form in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to insert a reservation form over an image that will be placed in the header of an hotel website.
I am using Sirvoy. They gave me a javascript code to paste into my website.
http://hotelporhe.com/index.php/es/
I want to place the form in the header, over the main image.

The code I have so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <table height="763" width="1424"
 background="http://hotelporhe.com/images/pruebaSlider3.jpg">
      <script async type="text/javascript" data-form-id="5671e222201aa" src="https://secured.sirvoy.com/widget/sirvoy.js"></script>>
      <tr>
          <td>Reserva hoy</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the specific code I am getting from Sirvoy:

```
 <script async type="text/javascript" data-form-id="5671e222201aa" src="https://secured.sirvoy.com/widget/sirvoy.js"></script>>
```

The image works but I cannot invoke the reservation form over my image.

I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is messed up, that's why it's not working. Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table height="763" width="1424"
 background="http://hotelporhe.com/images/pruebaSlider3.jpg"> 
<tr><td>    
<script async type="text/javascript" data-form-id="5671e222201aa" src="https://secured.sirvoy.com/widget/sirvoy.js"></script>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```